# How to convert a list of timestamps in hh:mm:ss format to minutes since midnight

Tags: python, timedelta

I have a Pandas dataframe with column for `appointmentStartTime` in `hh:mm:ss` format.  I'd like to get it into the minutes after midnight for that specific day.  For example, `5:00 AM` becomes `'300'`. I have seen solutions where you call current date and time and then subtract, but that's not quite going to fit my need here.

Code so far

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
file = C:\path\to\csv
taskData = pd.read_csv(os.path.basename(taskFile))
taskData.head()

row_id    appointmentStartTime
1         13:00:00
2         8:00:00
3         9:00:00
4         10:00:00


delta = timedelta(taskData.appointmentStartTime)
min_since_midnight = delta.total_minutes
display(min_since_midnight)
```

Here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-1578aa374224> in <module>
      2 #ex. 5:00 AM is 300 minutes after midnight
      3 
----> 4 delta = timedelta(taskData.appointmentStartTime)
      5 min_since_midnight = delta.total_minutes
      6 display(min_since_midnight)

TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt

def min_mid_night(t_str=str):
    time = dt.datetime.strptime(t_str, "%H:%M:%S")
    return time.hour*60 + time.minute
df2['min_from_mid_nigth'] = df2.appointmentStartTime.apply(min_mid_night)

   row_id appointmentStartTime  min_from_mid_nigth
0       1             13:00:00                 780
1       2              8:00:00                 480
2       3              9:00:00                 540
3       4             10:00:00                 600
```

Answer (score 1):

`taskData.appointmentStartTime` must be an `int`, `long` or `float` in order to be a valid argument for [`timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

> A `timedelta` object represents a duration, the difference between two
>   dates or times.
>
> `class datetime.timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[,milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])`
>
> All arguments are
>   optional and default to `0`. Arguments may be `ints`, `longs`, or `floats`,
>   and may be positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

I just will consider the first 12 hours after midnight and you can select any period of time

```
import datetime as DT
appointmentStartTime="10:00:00"  
_,d,h,m,s = (':0'*10+appointmentStartTime).rsplit(':',4)
r=0

t=DT.datetime.strptime(appointmentStartTime, '%H:%M:%S')
print(t.hour)
if int(t.hour)>=0 and int(t.hour)<=12 :
    r=(int(d)*24*60*60+int(h)*60*60+int(m)*60+int(s))/60
print(r )
#or convert any time period 
r=(int(d)*24*60*60+int(h)*60*60+int(m)*60+int(s))/60
print(r )
```